# Eigen: Sparse-Dense Product to Plain C++ Array

Tags: c++, matrix, product, eigen

I have this situation:
m is an NxN sparse matrix, and  p is plain C++ vector, that contains a NxN matrix.
I want to make the product m*p and store the result in a plain C++ array, of course, in a dense format.

```
 
  SparseMatrix  m; 
  double*p;
  Map mp(p,dim1,dim2);
  SparseTimeDenseProduct< Eigen::SparseMatrix, Eigen::Map< Eigen::Matrix< double, -1, -1> > > r = m*mp;
```

I have this code, but I don't know if is correct. And if is correct, I don't know how to ""extract"" the plain array of the SparseTimeDenseProduct.   How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to deal with Eigen's internal class. Simply do:

```
SparseMatrix<double> A(dim1,dim2);
double* p, res;
Map<const MatrixXd> mp(p,dim2,dim3);
Map<MatrixXd> mres(res,dim1,dim3);
mres = A * mp;
```

Comment: Incredibly simple. Thank you.